# WCF REST - Handle / in Get request

Tags: wcf, url, rest

How can i pass / character in a rest request ?

for example i have products with code like this CAB1/8TO1/8-25
and my rest url is like this "items/{code}"

Is there any way of handling this with a GET request?

Thanks

Comment: This is working items?code={code}

Answer (score 0):

You may try to URL encode it: `items/CAB1%2f8TO1%2f8-25`